# Patch environment vars in multiple test modules

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have these snippets

```
test_module1
@patch.dict(
    os.environ,
    {'ENV1': 'test',
     'ENV2': 'test2',
    },
)
@patch('module1.func1')
def test_1(mocked_func1):
    test_obj = {}
    source_of_truth = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    handler(test_obj)
    mocked_func1.assert_called_with(test_obj, source_of_truth)

test_module2
@patch.dict(
   os.environ,
   {'ENV1': 'test',
    'ENV2': 'test2',
   },
)
@patch('module2.func2')
def test_2(_):        
    result = checker()
    assert result == 'test/test2'
```

I am using pytest and when I run test_module1 and test_module2 separately boath are passing, but when I run them together the second one is failing with that error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`
and when I print `ENV1` and `ENV2` they are None really, but I can't understand why that is happening and how to deal with it. If someone can explain what is going on and how to do it correctly I will be greatful.